# How to prevent double rerender when I use props, useState and useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For example I have this component

```
const FooBar = (props) => {
  console.log("render")
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(props.foo)
  useEffect(() => {
    setFoo(props.foo)
  }, [props.foo])
  return (
    <div>
      {foo} <button onClick={() => setFoo(x => x + 1)}>component plus</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I can change it props like this

```
const App = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(1)
  return (
    <div>
      <FooBar foo={foo} />
      <button onClick={() => setFoo(x => x + 1)}>parent plus</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click on `parent plus` button the `FooBar` component will `rerender` two times. the first one is from props change and the second one is from `setFoo` inside `useEffect`.
How can I prevent second rerender?

Comment: You're mixing local state and props here. If you want to have a button change foo and also change foo with props, you should use some flux state management. Redux, useContext, or whatever you prefer.

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes, I can use global state, but if I use local state I just want to know how to prevent rerender when I update local state through props.

Comment: If you don't want to re render, why change props?

Comment: @HåkenLid I want to re render. I don't want to re render twice when I change props.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your goal with this example would be.
If you want to have two buttons that increment the same counter, than your code currently does not work as intended.

If you click the 'component plus' button several times and afterwards click the 'parent plus' button, your counter will reset to the value when you last clicked the parent button.

In case you want to pass state to child components, you usually do not want to save the passed state as the child components state. That will make it unnecessarily harder to sync up both states.

What you would do, is to pass the state and a function to set that state to the child component.

Your example would then look like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <div>
      <FooBar foo={foo} setFoo={setFoo} />
      <button onClick={() => setFoo(x => x + 1)}>parent plus</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const FooBar = props => {
  console.log("render");

  return (
    <div>
      {props.foo} <button onClick={() => props.setFoo(x => x + 1)}>component plus</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: My code is working as intended. I just don't want to re-render FooBar twice when I change props.

Comment: It's just an example. The use case is a component that can have its state updated both internally (via setFoo) and externally (via prop change).